# pagination in C# console application

Tags: c#, pagination, console

I have  around 300 entries to display and I want to display them in small blocks like 10 by 10 or 20 by 20 depending on the available empty lines on the console. I get the data either as a list or dictionary.

I actually want to have a similar behavior like the way "dir /p" command works. But this command prints out the list one by one when I hit the button. What I want is to print out the list 10 by 10

How I can arrange it on the code?

Note:  [This question is not the same with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214153/linq-selecting-range-of-records) as Skip() and Take() methods are not enough for what I want.

Comment: 300 entries where? In a database? And file, a list? a dictionary? What problem are you having so far? The pagination, identifying how many lines are available or something else?

Comment: It's not 100% the same issue, but please check the question I've linked with the duplicate close vote: it's almost the same approach, it has nothing to do with SQL.

Comment: Well, I get the data either as a list or dictionary. So I would say list and dictionary.

Comment: Well, I can not answer this question directly since it is labeled as duplicated. So I will give the answer as comment. As I explained in the question, Skip() and Take() methods are just a part of the solution. You should track the cursor position, buffer size and window size as well. The problem is when the cursor position exceeds the buffer size, you lose the track of the cursor. So you should have two cases in your algorithm.